# I can't find the dispatch related files in a rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't find the dispatch related files in a rails 3 app?

It was in the /public folder in the previous rails version right?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Never. It's not like standard PHP framework setups. The web server must be configured to, if the file is not found in public, pass the request to the Rack app all on its own.

In an Apache setup, this is Phusion Passenger's job. With servers like Mongrel or Thin, this is handled internally.

If you're interested in the actual ActionDispatch files, see `GEM_ROOT/actionpack-VERSION/lib/action_dispatch` (replace GEM_ROOT with where your gems are stored, and VERSION with the exact Rails version in question).

Comment: i guess the book the rails way is really out of date then!

Comment: @Blankman: haven't read it, so dunno. It seems to deal with Rails 2.0, so maybe things were different back before I hit the Rails scene. What does it say about dispatch files and public?

Comment: @Blankman: Ahh. It might be true if you're deploying with FCGI and `mod_ruby` you'll end up with a `public/dispatch.rb` file, but I'm not certain if that was part of Rails or a file that others would add. Regardless, that's not the strategy that people use these days.

Comment: Nothing is more useless than an out-of-date Rails book.